# Qt serial.readall is not working in 5.3.1

Tags: qt, qtserialport

`serial.readall` is returning an empty buffer in 5.3.1, but the same piece of code is working in 5.3.0. has anybody faced the same problem? Is there any workaround for this?

I am using Qt with MSVC 2010 windows 7. I have downloaded "Qt 5.3.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 537 MB)" from Qt downloads page.

My code:

```
portname=ui->lineEdit->text();
serial.setPortName(portname);
if(serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
{
    ui->pushButton_5->setText("Device Connected");
    ui->pushButton_5->setStyleSheet("background : yellow");
    if(!serial.setBaudRate((QSerialPort::Baud115200),QSerialPort::AllDirections))
                qDebug()<<serial.errorString();
    if(!serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8))
                qDebug()<<serial.errorString();
    if(!serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity))
                qDebug()<<serial.errorString();
    if(!serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop))
                qDebug()<<serial.errorString();
    if(!serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::HardwareControl))
                qDebug()<<serial.errorString();
}
else
{
     qDebug()<<"Serial port not opened. Error: "<<serial.errorString();
     QTest::qSleep(2000);
     exit(0);
}
serial.write(outbuff, l);
rsp=(serial.readAll()).toHex();
```

serial.readAll returns an empty buffer. I am getting response from the same HW when sent the same input from a different tool.

Comment: Can you provide some piece of code so that we can easily reproduce exactly your scenario?

Comment: I posted an answer here below... please check it out and tell me if it fixes your problem

Answer (score 0):

Reading from documentation:

> QByteArray QIODevice::readAll()
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Reads all available data from the device, and returns it as a
>   QByteArray.
>
> This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an empty
>   QByteArray() can mean either that no data was currently available for
>   reading, or that an error occurred.

The key fact here is that `readAll()` reads all data **available** from the device, but at the time you call `serial.readlAll()` you have no guarantees that the device you are waiting data from has already answered...

I think that the fact that the piece of code is working in Qt 5.3.0 is random...

You should use something like `serial.waitForReadyRead(...)` in your code (which will block the execution until there are available data to be read) prior to call to `serial.readAll()` or **BETTER** you should rework your code in order to connect a function to `readyRead()` signal of your `serial` object and then read the available data from that slot.

Comment: i even tried serial.waitForReadyRead() which returns false always. As I said same piece of code works in 5.3.0. Its not random. Problem lies in the 5.3.1. Thank you.